# How to make tensorflow use GPU on a Windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I am struggling with making tensorflow run on GPU on my MSI Windows 10 machine with NVIDIA GeForce 960M. I think I used already all hints available on internet on this topic and I am not able to succeed, so the question is, whether you can give me any additional hint on that, which could help me in achieving the goal -
 which is running tensorflow on a GPU?

To bo more specific:

- I am using Anaconda 4.4.1 with the python version 3.6.1.
- I have followed the installation instruction proveided here:
  https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

So, I downloaded and installed CUDA Toolkit 8.0 (I downloaded the file *cuda_8.0.61_win10.exe* and the file with a patch *cuda_8.0.61.2_windows.exe*). I executed both of them and let them run with the standard options. Then, to check whether the installation was successfull, I compiled deviceQuery from the CUDA Samples set and successfully executed it. See the results below:

```
<pre>
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v8.0\bin\win64\Debug>deviceQuery.exe
deviceQuery.exe Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 960M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147483648 bytes)
  ( 5) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     640 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1176 MHz (1.18 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 960M
Result = PASS
</pre>
```

...so it looks OK, at least for me... Then I downloaded and unpacked cuDNN v5.1. Additionally I have added manualy the path to the dll file of that library to the PATH system variable. I checked also, whether my graphics card was listed in the list of compatible devices and it was.

- Then I installed tensorflow. For that I used the following command:

  ```
  *pip install tensorflow-gpu*
  ```

It was installed without any error messages. The last message was:

```
Successfully installed tensorflow-1.3.0 tensorflow-gpu-1.3.0
```

- I tried to run a simple python program to check, whether tensoflow is
  working.

The program was:

```
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = "/gpu:0"  # ...it works fine with "/cpu:0"; it doesn't with "/gpu:0"
with tf.device(device_name):
    ran_matrix = tf.random_uniform(shape=(1,1), minval=0, maxval=1)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    result = sess.run(ran_matrix)
    print(result)
```

...and the result was (unfortunatelly) as in the screenshot below. I executed it from the level of PyCharm.

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFpqy.png)

The most important error message was:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'random_uniform/sub': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
     [[Node: random_uniform/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/device:GPU:0"](random_uniform/max, random_uniform/min)]]
```

Additionally I tried to run the same program using CPU instead of GPU. To do that I changed the parameter in the following line: *device_name = "/cpu:0"*

...and it worked fine...

I searched the internet for hints, what can be wrong here, but I cannot find any specific answer (most of discussions concern problems in Ubuntu and I am using Windows 10 and I cannot change it).

Where should I start to get the problem solved?

Comment: Could you try running `python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"` and show its results (preferably copy&pasted, not a screenshot)?

Comment: The result, which I get is: 1.3.0

Comment: then it looks like tensorflow can't detect the CUDA .dll files; a list of them should have been printed by that command. Can't really help more, not using windows myself. But maybe try reinstalling tensorflow, or moving CUDA dlls to some directory where python will find them, or adding the directory they lie in to the PATH variable…

Comment: I've just solved the problem by reinstalling tensorflow-gpu and all dependent libraries (I was trying to do it already one month ago, but by that time it did not work; right now it finally worked fine :-)). Some of the dependent libraries had new versions for sure, but I am not able to say, which one was probably the root cause of the problem. Anyway - everything works fine now. Thank you for your interest in my question and for your suggestion to reinstall tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved the problem by reinstalling tensorflow-gpu and all dependent libraries (I was trying to do it already one month ago, but by that time it did not work; right now it finally worked fine :-)). Some of the dependent libraries had new versions for sure, but I am not able to say, which one was probably the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

check this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12416

I faced same issue after updating tf from 1.2 to 1.3, and fixed it by updating cuDNN v6.0.

Comment: I've just tried updating cuDNN to v6.0, as well as to v7.0 and it has not helped, unfortunatelly.